# How do I validate integer in ruby

Tags: ruby, validation, input

I am asking user for his or her age , I am using `gets` method for it ,

This is what I am currently  doing

```
  age = gets.chomp.to_i 
  puts age
```

My problem is when user enter `12a` something then also it takes input and store `12` in age field ,I just want only integers.

How can I do this ?

Comment: You can use a regular expression to check whether the result from `gets.chomp` is digits-only. (or whatever format you want to allow)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps something like this:

```
begin
  age = Integer(gets)
rescue ArgumentError => e
  puts "Only integers allowed!"
  retry
end
```

`Integer(gets)` will return an integer for something like `"12\n"` but will raise an `ArgumentError` for `"12a\n"`.

`rescue ArgumentError` will only rescue from that `ArgumentError` will print an error message and that `retry` will bring you back to the `begin`...

Answer (score 1):

We got something new for [Kernel::Integer](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Kernel.html#method-i-Integer) in Ruby v2.6!

```
age = loop do
  print "How old are you?: "
  str = gets.chomp
  age = Integer(str, exception: false)
  if age.nil?
    puts "That's not an integer. Try again"
  elsif age < 0
    puts "Negative integers are not permitted. Try again"
  elsif age < 30
    puts "'Cmon, you've got to be at least 30. Try again"
  else
    break age
  end
end
```

A possible dialog:

```
How old are you?: cat
That's not an integer. Try again
How old are you?: -44
Negative integers are not permitted. Try again
How old are you?: 28
'Cmon, you've got to be at least 30. Try again
How old are you?: 35
  #=> 35 
age
  #=> 35
```